# Javascript Object prototype confusion (with require.js and three.js)

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js, requirejs, prototype

Essentially what I'm confused about has something to do with either my understanding of Objects / prototypes, require.js or three.js. Here's an example:

#### TLDR:

**"wee" is an instance of "Wee" which is a wrapper/monkey patch of THREE...**

**Shouldn't "wee" therefore have properties and methods of THREE?**

(Transitive property and whatnot: a = b = c; a = c.)

```
define (['three'], function () {
    function WEE(){
      THREE;
      return THREE;
    }
    var test = new WEE;
    console.log("test");
    console.log(test);
    function Wee(){
      WEE.call(this);
      this.prototype = new WEE();
      this.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.height = window.innerHeight;
      this.aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    }
    var wee = new Wee();
    console.log("wee");
    console.log(wee);
});
```

This is where I start to get confused...

The 'test' log in chrome shows:

```
test
Object {REVISION: "66", CullFaceNone: 0, CullFaceBack: 1, CullFaceFront: 2, CullFaceFrontBack: 3…}
```

which is good. My goal was to create a monkey patch of three.js.

However, when I log 'wee in chrome it shows:

```
 wee
 Wee {prototype: Object, width: 1920, height: 1102, aspectRatio: 1.7422867513611615}
```

expanding the prototype detail thing I can see that the prototype is Wee, which is THREE- which is also good... but what's confusing me is that later in my code I do this:

```
var renderer = new wee.WebGLRenderer();
```

and it returns "undefined".

I've also tried

```
var renderer = wee.WebGLRenderer;
var renderer = wee.WebGLRenderer();
```

all of which fail with "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

### Questions:

1. What's going on?
2. What am I missing?
3. Why does THREE work at all in the first place, being that my define function requires it but doesn't assign it to anything?
4. Am I asking the right question? What would be a different way to phrase it so I can just google it next time?

Comment: Inside your `WEE` function, the line `THREE;` is very suspicious and I suspect it doesn't do what you think it does. It's a no-op if `THREE` is an in-scope variable; it throws a `ReferenceError` otherwise. It has no other effect.

Comment: FYI, `new WEE()`, simple returns `THREE`. So you could as well just write `var test = THREE;`. And `WEE.call(this)` doesn't do anything either since you are not doing anything with `this` inside `WEE`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's what I thought too but for some reason it doesn't throw an error anywhere.

Comment: @FelixKling The idea is that WEE will eventually be a factory function, I just haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: @AndrewLuhring: `THREE` must be defined, then. So it's a no-op: It retrieves the value of the `THREE` variable, and then doesn't do anything with it. You can just delete the line `THREE;` entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
this.prototype = new WEE();
```

creates a property on the object called `prototype`. It does nothing to set the underlying prototype of the object (which isn't called `prototype`; it's anonymous in the standard for now, some implementations call it `__proto__`). You might as well have called that property `robert`.

The prototype of an object is set (for now) in one of two ways:

1. If you create the object via `new FunctionName`, its underlying prototype is set from whatever `FunctionName.prototype` refers to when you use the `new` operator.
2. If you create the object via `Object.create`, it's whatever you pass into `Object.create` to assign the prototype.

So:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: 42
};
var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar); // 42
```

And

```
var f = Object.create({
    bar: 42
});
console.log(f.bar); // 42
```

But notably:

```
function Foo() {
    this.prototype = {
        bar: 42
    };
}
var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar);           // undefined
console.log(f.prototype.bar); // 42
```

Note that creating a property called `prototype` on the instance created by `new Foo` doesn't do anything to set the prototype of that instance.

This is one of the great confusions of JavaScript: The `prototype` property on functions is not the prototype of the function, it's the prototype that `new` will assign to an object if you create the object via `new FunctionName`. Objects don't have any named property that represents their prototype (for now, cross-implementation).

In ES6 (the next version of the spec), the `__proto__` property accessor is very, very likely to be defined to allow us to directly access and set the prototype of an object. (It's in the draft specs, which means it's cleared multiple levels of review; I can't see it being removed at this point.) Currently SpiderMonkey (Firefox's JavaScript engine) supports that, and a couple of others may as well, but it's not standard.

Comment: Ha, I thought `__proto__` is not going to be part of the standard. But you are right. I guess there was some back and forth.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, I didn't follow it, but I bet it was a fiery discussion.

Comment: For the record- @T.J.Crowder you answered my main question; the only reason I haven't marked it as the answer yet is because I also need answers to 3. and 4. I don't want to mark it as answered yet cause then no one will look at it and I'll still be left in the dark about 3. and 4.

Comment: @AndrewLuhring: Can't help you with #3, except to say that I don't see why it *wouldn't* work if you're asking something to include it. Re #4, you used reasonable terms, seems to me.